# Plotting Ireland's coastline using Basemap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I'd like to know how to plot the coastline of Ireland in Basemap.  I'd like to plot the whole of the UK using Basemap, however I cannot get the coastline of Ireland to plot.  I've also tried `map.drawcountries(linewidth = 0.2)`, `map.fillcontinents(color = 'lightgray', zorder = 0)`, and `map.drawmapboundary(linewidth = 0.2)` but none of these give the coastline I'm after.

I'm sure Ireland has a coastline, as I've seen it in real life.  Thanks in advance.

[image: No Ireland]

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
map = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0 = 55, lon_0 = -4,
    resolution = 'i', area_thresh = 0.05,
    llcrnrlon=-9, llcrnrlat=49,
    urcrnrlon=2, urcrnrlat=61)
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 0.2, zorder = 0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That is strange. Have you tried adjusting the boundaries of your map (e.g. `llcrnrlon=-12`)? Obviously Ireland should be shown in your map, but perhaps something strange is happening during clipping.

Comment: Setting `llcrnrlon=-8.9` works.  It simply doesn't work for -9.  Strange.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but you could try this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

`fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 map = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0 =  53.866772, lon_0 = -5.23636,resolution = 'i', area_thresh = 0.05,llcrnrlon=-10.65073, llcrnrlat=49.16209,urcrnrlon=1.76334, urcrnrlat=61)
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 0.2, zorder = 0)
plt.show()`

Comment: Thanks.  As per the comments on the original question, it seems it can be plotted for almost any value for `llcrnrlon` apart from -9.  If I change this in your answer, it still doesn't work.